# how to clear textbox value in selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

and this is my code

```
WebElement formElement1 = wd.findElement(By.id("updateMasterform"));
List<WebElement> allFormChildElements1 = formElement.findElements(By.xpath("*"));
for (WebElement we : allFormChildElements1) {
        System.out.println(we.getAttribute("class"));      
}
formElement1.findElement(By.id("editClientName")).clear();
formElement1.findElement(By.id("editClientName")).sendKeys("Mumbai");
```

Comment: You used `.clear()` in the code you posted... what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just use type method and enter "" as input:

```
formElement1.findElement(By.id("editClientName")).sendKeys("")
```

Comment: What is sending "" going to do that `.clear()` and `.sendKeys("Mumbai")` isn't already doing?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes clear doesn't work if the text box have no focus
Try below code to clear a value in text box if clear doesn't work: 
formElement1.findElement(By.id("editClientName")).sendkeys(Keys.chord(keys.CONTROL,'a'))
formElement1.findElement(By.id("editClientName")).sendKeys(Keys.DELETE);